# Can I automatically add shared examples to certain tests?

Tags: rspec

I would like to run a shared example automatically if the `described_class` matches some description.

For example, when I have a module I often write a shared example and include it into anything which includes the module.

```
module ExtraStuff
  def self.stuff
    42
  end
end

class Thing
  include ExtraStuff
end

shared_examples ExtraStuff do
  it 'has stuff' do
    expect( described_class.stuff ).to eq 42
  end
end

describe Thing do
  it_behaves_like ExtraStuff
end
```

But sometimes I forget. Or it's included into many classes and its tedious to add `it_behaves_like` to every class.

`config.before` does not work because "*`it_behaves_like` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc)*".

Comment: Sorry to be this guy... but the specs are all about specifying how your code should behave. IDK how big your project is, but if it's more than 3 people are contributing to this codebase you probably should not do that. (If I think of a way to actually do that, I'll post a real answer)

Comment: @Grzegorz You're right that if one accidentally removes a module inclusion the test will also disappear. OTOH we've been forgetting to include shared tests at all. Perhaps an automated code check would be a better solution, but that's another question.

Comment: Maybe what you need to improve is the code review process? Maybe TDD-ish approach would help? Maybe custom RuboCop cop (class including specific module, but RSpec not testing the behavior)?